# virt-install automated fedora vm installation using kickstart file

Tags: fedora, kvm

I am trying to provision a fedora37 server using the KVM virtualization. I have the fedora server iso locally downloaled and using the below virt-install command to do the automated provision using the kickstart file. Here are the details

ISO

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 admin admin 2459566080 Feb 28 10:55 /home/admin/Downloads/Fedora-Server-dvd-x86_64-37-1.7.iso
```

Command

```
$ virt-install --name test1.stack.com \
--description 'test1.stack.com' \
--metadata name="test1",title="test1" \
--memory 4096 \
--vcpus 2 \
--location /home/admin/Downloads/Fedora-Server-dvd-x86_64-37-1.7.iso \
--os-variant fedora37 \
--disk size=40 \
--network bridge=virbr0 \
--initrd-inject /home/admin/middleware/stack/kickstartfiles/ks.cfg \
--extra-args "inst.ks=file:/ks.cfg console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8"
```

Kickstart file

```
$ cat ks.cfg 
# Generated by Anaconda 37.12.6
# Generated by pykickstart v3.41
#version=DEVEL
# Use graphical install
#graphical
install
# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'
# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8

# Network information
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=enp1s0 --ipv6=auto --activate
network  --hostname=test1.stack.com

# Use CDROM installation media
#cdrom
#location /home/admin/Downloads/Fedora-Server-dvd-x86_64-37-1.7.iso

%packages
@^server-product-environment

%end

# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --enable

# Generated using Blivet version 3.5.0
ignoredisk --only-use=vda
autopart
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --none --initlabel

# System timezone
timezone Asia/Kolkata --utc

# Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $y$j9T$T6q2l9wDCgMeAx03V5ROu0EV$VMvuTdW3C53YO81zP0X6oRTWmgw08FGp9yXiSZRdLmC
user --groups=wheel --name=admin --password=$y$j9T$pfrDLFU0igHpjBUcrBEFxjYL$HyupPZODgb.ihZhywInuu2iXb7lcXO2CsBnyrHknptB --iscrypted --gecos="admin"
```

But the vm provisioning using the kickstart file just gets stuck for hours at the following stage as shown in the screenshot.

Kindly suggest if i am missing anything here. If i remove the --initrd-inject and --extra-args from the install command it launched the textual interface from where i can manually configure and proceed with the installation but i wanted those configuration to be carried out by the kickstart file which is getting stuck right now.

[image]